# Keep vertex order when exporting and re-importing a mesh

Tags: python, vertex-weights, stl

I'm having a problem with exporting my mesh and keeping the vertex order when re-importing that exported mesh. I have looked around but was unable to find a good answer.

I'm helping a friend with his project which he is developing in python. He wants me to export a model in .stl format together with joint positions and vertex weights, so he can do his own animation in his code.

Mesh is exported via Blender interface and the vertex weights are exported to JSON via a python script. In JSON I have key-value pairs, where keys are bone names and values are arrays of vertex weights from vertex 0 to last vertex.

Exporting all of the above is no problem, however I have noticed that when I re-import the exported model, the vertex with index 0 is no longer the same vertex. I'm affraid that when he uses the list of exported weights to assign those weights to verdex, he will assign wrong values due to the mixed order.

I understand that .fbx saves animated model, which would solve the above problem, but he is having issues working with that format.

How can I guarantee that the vertex order stays the same?
I thought the issue was with .stl format, because it saves faces and then the order is lost, but I'm having the same problem with .obj. If I open it with notepad++ I can see that .obj has a list of vertices.
Why is the vertex order lost?
When is the vertex order lost? Is this an issue of exporting or importing?
I tried using "keep vertex order" with .obj file, but so far, no luck...

Besides switching to .fbx format, what could I do to keep the vertex order?

Comment: Hello, I don't think you can ensure vertex order when using custom exporters and exporters in different formats. You could use Python to tweak the content of the generated file if it's not a proprietary format, by keeping track of the index and world position of vertices before export for instance